# SwiftUI TextField binding to Double not working with custom Formatter

Tags: swiftui

I have a Binding to a Double parameter that is set by a SwiftUI `TextField`.    I use a custom `Formatter` that converts to and from a Double value.   The `TextField` sends an empty string `""` to the `Formatter` upon editing so the conversion fails and the `Double` parameter is not updated.   The struct is called from a parent View which has a `@ObjectBinding` parameter and the `Double` is a parameter of that object.

I am currently using Xcode 11 beta 3 and macOS Catalina Beta 3.    The `TextField` works if the parameter is a `String`.   The problem appears to be that a non-String type, which requires a `Formatter` fails to properly update the `@Binding` value.
Here is the `Formatter`:

```swift
public class DoubleFormatter: Formatter {

    override public func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        var retVal: String?
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

        if let dbl = obj as? Double {
            retVal = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: dbl))
        } else {
            retVal = nil
        }

        return retVal
    }

    override public func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

        var retVal = true

        if let dbl = Double(string), let objok = obj {
            objok.pointee = dbl as AnyObject?
            retVal = true
        } else {
            retVal = false
        }

        return retVal

    }
}
```

Here is the SwiftUI View that takes the Double parameter in a TextField

```swift
struct HStackTextTextField : View {
    var text: String
    @Binding var value: Double
    @State var valueState: Double

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(value)") //shows the value failing to update 
            TextField("Number", value: $value, formatter: DoubleFormatter()) //Still Fails
            Text("\(valueState)") //shows valueState updating properly
            TextField("Number", value: $valueState, formatter: DoubleFormatter()) //works as expected
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the `TextField` value to update when I type, but it does not.   When I trace the value in the the Formatter.   The string provided to `getObjectValue` is `""` instead of the value in the `TextField`.

UPDATE: As of catalina/Xcode beta 5, this still appears to be an issue when the `View` `TextField` parameter is defined as `@Binding` and passed to the `View`.  It appears to work as expected if the `TextField` parameter is defined as `@State` and is local to the View.

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue with Xcode 11 GM 2/macOS 10.15 Beta 8

Comment: Here we are more than a year later and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is a bug in SwiftUI. (See my similar question: [SwiftUI TextField with formatter not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799456/swiftui-textfield-with-formatter-not-working))

In beta 2, it didn't work at all. In beta 3, I think you'll find that your result gets passed to your formatter if (and only if) you hit return after typing in the field. Hopefully in beta 4 they'll finish fixing the bug!

Comment: I edited the original issue, because the issue appears to be that a @Binding will not work properly with the TextField and formatter

Answer (score 3):

SwiftUI 3.0 still facing the same issue when using custom formatter in TextField. In my case I was using number formatter with 2 fractions. Here is my workgaround I found which looks legit and works correctly. I used custom binding.

```
@Binding var amount: Double?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        let amountBinding = Binding(
            get: { self.amount ?? 0.0 },
            set: { self.amount = Double(String(format:"%.2f", $0))})
        TextField("€", value: amountBinding, formatter: NumberFormatters.twoFractionDigits, onEditingChanged: { changed in
            // Editing changed
        })
        Spacer()
    }
}


struct NumberFormatters {
    static var twoFractionDigits: Formatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .none
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }
}
```