# SwiftUI Textfield format onEditingChanged

Tags: swiftui

I have a formatted SiwftUI TextField and I want it to format when editing changes. What would be the correct way of doing that?

```
TextField("", value: $binding, formatter: $formatter,
                    onEditingChanged: { (editingChanged) in
                        //How to force formatting here?
                    },
                    onCommit: {
                        //Here formatting happens.
                })
```

Comment: Don't use that variant of constructor, use instead proxy binding as in [SwiftUI TextField with formatter not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799456/swiftui-textfield-with-formatter-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

OnEditing closure is called when the editing mode of the TextField changes. So it would be called with true when you start editing and called with false when you end (and so would onCommit at the end unless you cancel, but need to check).

I don't think that's what you want. If you want to format while the user is changing the text in the TextField, try something like this:

```
  TextField("text", text: $text).padding()
            .onReceive(text.publisher) { (c) in
                print("Got \(c)")
                self.text = self.text.uppercased()
        }
```

But, keep in mind when you apply the formatting to $text, the new formatted version will be published, triggering a second closure call. This double call may or may not be an issue depending on the formatting you want and how text is used elsewhere.