# SwiftUI TextField + Stepper

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, stepper

I'm trying to implement a TextField with a number input together with Stepper to control quantity.
After entering a number in the TextField the Stepper loses the ability to change the number.
I'm pretty sure there is a trick with Binding value, but can't figure out what exactly.

```
struct TestView: View {
  @State var quantity: Int = 0

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      TextField("", value: $quantity, formatter: NumberFormatter())
      Stepper("", onIncrement: {
        self.quantity += 1
      }, onDecrement: {
        self.quantity -= 1
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because using `NumberFormatter` in `TextField` is [bugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799456/swiftui-textfield-with-formatter-not-working).

You may need to use a custom binding instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quantity: Int = 0

    static let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    var binding: Binding<String> {
        .init(get: {
            "\(self.quantity)"
        }, set: {
            self.quantity = Int($0) ?? self.quantity
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("", text: binding)
            Stepper("", onIncrement: {
                self.quantity += 1
            }, onDecrement: {
                self.quantity -= 1
            })
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also don't recreate `NumberFormatter` every time:

```
TextField("", value: $quantity, formatter: NumberFormatter())
```

You can use a static property which is only created once:

```
static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
```

Answer (score 0):

> After entering a number in the TextField the Stepper loses the ability
> to change the number.

I was facing this issue too and actually found that the `onIncrement` and `onDecrement` actions continue to be accordingly fired. However, I noticed that engaging with the `Stepper` doesn't release the user focus on the `TextField` as observed through the continued blinking cursor.

**Removing the focus from the `TextField` while the user engages with the `Stepper` resolves the issue.**

This also makes sense when consulting the `TextField` documentation:

> If the value is a string, the text field updates this value continuously as the user types or otherwise edits the text in the field. For non-string types, it updates the value when the user commits their edits, such as by pressing the Return key.

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield)

As such, I'd recommend simulating user commit events when the user engages with the `Stepper`. This avoids unnecessarily type-casting and allows you to continue to take advantage of the `TextField` `formatter` initialiser.

Example modification of the original code:

```
struct TestView: View {
  @State var quantity: Int = 0

  // Keep track of which field the user is focused on
  @FocusState private var focusedField: String?

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      TextField("", value: $quantity, formatter: NumberFormatter())
        .focused($focusedField, equals: "quantity")
      Stepper("", onIncrement: {
        // Remove the focus from the (text) field
        focusedField = nil

        self.quantity += 1
      }, onDecrement: {
        // Remove the focus from the (text) field
        focusedField = nil

        self.quantity -= 1
      })
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, also see the `focused(_:equals:)` and `@FocusState` documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focused(_:equals:)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/FocusState