# TextField numeric validation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

In order to handle the textfield numeric validation, I try to write an observable object in order to check if the input is a number. However, I found that the value was reset and I cannot show the original value of the field.

Here is my code.

```
struct editor: View {
    @ObservedObject var food: Food
    @ObservedObject var count = NumericInputValidator()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
                    TextField("\(self.food.count)", text: $count.value) // $count.value always = 0
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.count.value = String(food.count)
            print(self.count.value) // correct
            print(food.count) // correct
            }
        )
    }
}
```

You can assume that my food structure contains a variable count in CoreData

```
@NSManaged public var count: Int16
```

The validator as follow:

```
class NumericInputValidator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var value = "" {
        didSet {
            let filteredValue = value.filter { $0.isNumber }
            if value != filteredValue {
                value = filteredValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On Appear, i assume that the value of count already assigned to count.value, hence it should appear as $count.value in the textfield. However, results show that it is always 0. Why it is the case?

Comment: Off-topic but your validator needs to be improved, if the user adds a double value say 4.5 the output will be 45.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66921708/2303865

Comment: Did you check the answer posted in your question above? It shows how to add a Binding to update your value.

Comment: btw iCharacter property `isNumber` will return `true` for fraction values  like `⅚` as well. What you need is `value.filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0) }`